# Bootstrap doesn't detect JQuery unless I import it from url

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, electron

```html
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

First one will give the 'Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined' error on bootstrap.
Second one wont.

I have tried with many different versions of JQuery. I'm using electron and nodejs. The version that I'm using right now of Jquery is correctly detected and is the same as the google's one.

JQuery is installed in NodeJS.

Comment: Do you actually _have_ a `js/jquery.min.js` file, like you probably have a `js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Now it isn't even detected with the google file. But yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it but this is how I've been setting up `JQuery` and `Bootstrap` for a few years now. With `Electron 5`, I had to set `nodeintegration: true` when creating the window in order to use `require` (I guess I could just link to `JQuery` instead).

All the libs are installed through `npm`.

```
    <script>
        if (typeof module === 'object') { window.module = module; module = undefined; }
    </script>
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```